# How to format a datetime to GMT irrespective of regional settings?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have a datetime stored in the database as GMT. I need to format this datetime as a string together with the timezone offset to UTC, for example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2012-03-15 12:49:23");
string dateAsString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
```

2012-03-15T12:49:23.000+00:00

This code works on my machine in the UK. When I change my regional settings to a different time zone, for example Perth, I get the following output:

2012-03-15T12:49:23.000+08:00

I need the string output to always represent the time in GMT.

Answer (score 5):

It's awkward. First you need to parse it appropriately, then format it appropriately... it's easiest to go via `DateTimeOffset`. (I'm assuming you intend the input string to be treated as if it's in UTC? You haven't made this clear.)

You can use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` so that you end up with a UTC value after the `Parse` step. You can then create a `DateTimeOffset` from that `DateTime` value, so it will have an offset of 0.

Assuming you have a fixed format input, I would *strongly* advise that you use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `DateTime.Parse`, too. (Actually, I'd probably advise you to use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) instead, but that's a different matter...)

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var parsed = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-03-15 12:49:23",
                                         "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                         DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |
                                         DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
        var dtOffset = new DateTimeOffset(parsed);
        var output = dtOffset.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }                   
}
```