# using .NET TimeZoneInfo Pacific Standard Time (PST) versus Pacific Daylight Time (PDT)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

The following Stackoverflow Q/A seems to be saying that the .NET TimeZoneInfo class will correctly observe daylight savings time (DST) when converting a UTC to PST or PDT with the single TimeZoneInfo code "Pacific Standard Time":

[How do I convert UTC to PST or PDT depending upon what the current time is in California?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013780/how-do-i-convert-utc-to-pst-or-pdt-depending-upon-what-the-current-time-is-in-ca)

If this is correct, how would TimeZoneInfo achieve this? I understand that you can look at the UTC day and month of the year and get close to identifying when PDT is, during the late winter through mid-fall, but the exact dates of when day light savings is observed are slightly different each year...

Or am I wrong in assuming that TimeZoneInfo handles PDT and PST (aka observes DST) with the single TimeZoneInfo code "Pacific Standard Time:?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer here:
[Convert PST to GMT Irrespective of Server Timezone with .Net DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047541/convert-pst-to-gmt-irrespective-of-server-timezone-with-net-datetime)

Excerpt:
"This function `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(uTcDateTime, TimeZoneInfo)` uses a timezone database that's stored in the registry and maintained by Windows. Timezone rules change over time, particularly daylight savings transitions, so keeping Windows Update active on that machine is important to allow Microsoft to update the database."